# Xaml Default Style for Type

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a default style set for images that I wanted to have for all my images in my application (put in Application Resources):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/> <!--To obviously see that it works-->
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I have an image somewhere else with a style like

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            ... set some other properties here
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

the base style is not applied. If I put a

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Image}}"
```

everything works as (I) expected.

Is there a way to apply a default style without going through all my xaml and add the `BasedOn` to every styled image?

---

**EDIT:**

I often have some kind of DataTriggers in ther like:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="VAR1">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/MyApp;component/Resources/Var1.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="VAR2">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/MyApp;component/Resources/Var2.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

So by declaring a new style you're effectively overriding the default. The `BasedOn` is necessary to inherit elements from another style template (in this case your default) so what you're seeing is an expected result.

You can however forego the additional templates and just declare the properties at the instance level so you don't need to reference another template.

So instead of a new template like you have now;

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            ... set some other properties here
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

You would just in-line the properties like;

```
<Image Property="Value" Property="Value" Property="Value"/>
```

Then the `Image` will still inherit from the default, but the specific properties will only be overridden at the instance instead of the entire template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Get your idea! But I often work with `Style.Triggers` in connection with `DataTrigger` to switch some Image Sources. I guess that would be hard to write as in-line...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, would maybe need an example. Either way once you declare a new Style, the original is overridden unless you reference it with `BasedOn`, that's just the way it is. :/